# How render method escape_javascript with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to replacing all the messages with the new ones and once again set the timer to fire off. But script index.js.erb dont render messages.

I do following:

**polling.coffee:**

```
window.Poll = ->
  setTimeout ->
    $.get('/messages')
  , 5000

jQuery ->
  Poll() if $('#messages').size() > 0
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#messages').find('.media-list').html('#{<%= escape_javascript(render(
                                   :partial => @messages,
                                   :layout => false
                                    ))%>}');

window.Poll();
```

I added //= require polling in application.js

**new.html.haml**

```
- if current_user
  .panel.panel-default#messages
    .panel-body
      %ul.media-list
        = render @messages

  .page-header
    %h1 Join the discussion!
  = render "form"
- else
  visit root_path
```

What wrong with escape_javascript(render....  ? How correct pass to HAML?

More code:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @messages = Message.order('created_at ASC')
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    @messages = Message.order('created_at ASC')
  end

  def create
    respond_to do |format| 
      @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
      if @message.save
        flash[:success] = 'Your message was successfully posted!'
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Your message cannot be post!'
      end

      format.html{ redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    end  
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the `#{}` for inside the single-quoted string? ERB files use `<%= %>` to output text.

Comment: I deleted #{} and changed to double quotes, dont work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? What's being rendered? (By the JS template.)

Comment: nothing. I send message A from  user A. Than from other browser i send message B from user B. displaying in window only message B. Message A display only after reload browser. Dont rendered **html('#{<%= escape_javascript(render(
                                   :partial => @messages,..**

Comment: When it makes the request look in the network tab in your browser and see what's coming back. (As written it looks like it'll only start polling if there are any messages to begin with in the first place, so you'd have to validate it's being called at all.)

Comment: thank you Dave. I will try.